# Do I need a TURN server?

Tags: webrtc, turn

In which cases should I use TURN servers?

Right now I have a WebRTC app that works perfectly. The app is going to be released.

Do I need to set up my own TURN server or maybe this is the case only for major apps?

Answer (score 11):

WebRTC can connect in a few ways, and falls down progressively to lower preference choices as it fails at its first choices.

1. naive direct p2p with own ip
2. if that fails, use a STUN server to determine what ip (e.g., router) we're behind
3. if that fails, true p2p is not possible, use a TURN server instead to relay traffic.

On a typical webRTC app, about 20% of connections require a TURN server. It may work fine for you, but try accessing your webRTC service from a cell phone connection (which will usually require TURN), and you'll see that not all connections are equal when it comes to p2p.

[image: https://www.frozenmountain.com/developers/blog/webrtc-nat-traversal-methods-a-case-for-embedded-turn]

This picture shows which types of connections for each party's NAT results in the need for TURN as opposed to STUN.

Comment: Nice recap table.

Comment: I though tit was great. I found it somewhere else, just tried to make sure it was available here on SO.

Answer (score 2):

There are already good, and clear writings, and discussion on this topics. You might want to go through them -

- https://www.callstats.io/blog/2017/10/26/turn-webrtc-products
- https://bloggeek.me/turn-public-ip-address/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that your app works almost always then you should use a TURN server. If you are fine with it working in only in some cases, then don't use a TURN server.

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC with a STUN server but without TURN server was not working with a VPN.

For example, if 2 peers were on a different network (WAN) and someone was using a VPN, I had to use a TURN server.